# Which parameter gives better qualitative measure among arrays of numbers?

Tags: statistics

I have 3 arrays:

```
A1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 5]
A2 = [1, 1, 1, 2, 4]
A3 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

I want a parameter which would prefer A1 (an array having "more small values" even though total sums are almost equal) over rest arrays.

Before I thought of just adding all elements in an array then comparing all three of them. Then I realised this method will not work.

Note: The number 3 Arrays is just for illustration of my intensions. In actual scenario there could be 10000's of such arrays and I would to pick the best one using the suggested parameter's value.

Comment: You can use median, I suppose. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median . Right now you're basically comparing averages. But really, to find the right parameter, you need to describe what you want better than just "more small values".

Answer (score 0):

In a technical sense 'parameter' refers to a property of a distribution and
'statistic' refers to a summary based on values in a sample.

I suppose you want a statistic that expresses the 'typical' value of each
array. Frequently used statistics are the mean (total divided by sample size),
median (middle value of sorted data; average of middle two if there the
number of elements is even), and mode (most frequent value, if there is one)

For $A_i,$ the mean is 1.8, the median is 1, and there is a mode at 1.

For $A_2,$ the mean is 1.8, the median is 1, and there is a mode at 1.

For $A_3,$ the mean is 1.8, the median is 2, and there is no mode.

There are many other specialized statistics that measure 'location', some
developed for special applications. A *20% trimmed mean* might be of
interest for your three arrays. To begin, 20% of the observations are
removed from the low and high ends of the sorted data, respectively, and
then the remaining observations (in your case, three of them) are
averaged. For $A_1, A_2, A_3$ the 20% trimmed means are $1.000, 1.333, 1.667,$
respectively.

If you really want to focus on the smaller values, you might want to use
one of the lower quantiles. The *40th percentile* of an arrays of
five elements would be the second highest of the sorted data: in your example,
$1$ for each array. (Different software packages and different textbooks
use slightly different definitions of quantiles.)

You need to try to clarify exactly what property of your arrays you want
a statistic to express. Then you may be able to decide which statistic to use.
With only your brief description to go on, I guess the median or the trimmed
mean might be best.

*Note:* You gave examples with only five elements per array, so I used a 20% trimmed mean for an illustration. For larger arrays it might be
better to use the more common 5% trimmed mean.